# how to use mvrnorm for multiple mean vector in R

Tags: r, loops, normal-distribution

`mu` is the matrix of two mean vectors (col-1 and col-2 are two mean vectors)

```
mu=matrix(c(1,5,4,
                5,8,9), nrow =3,ncol=2)
mu
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    1    5
    [2,]    5    8
    [3,]    4    9
```

And the corresponding covariance matrices are as

```
sig1=matrix(c(diag(1,3,3),
            diag(4,3,3)), nrow = 3, ncol = 3*2, byrow = F)
sig1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    4    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    4    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    4
```

The first three column is the covarince matrix for mean vector-1(i,e col-1 of `mu`) and last three is for mean vector-2(i,e, col-2 of `mu`)
I would like to use `mvrnorm` to generate data for each mean vector and covariance matrix

I would like to create a matrix of order `2 by 3` where the first row is the output of `mvrnorm(1,mu[,1],sig1[,1:3])` and the second row is the output of `mvrnorm(1,mu[,2],sig1[,4:6])`
Can I do it using any loop or bulit-in function?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you open to defining your covariance matrix by `sig1 = Matrix::bdiag(diag(3), diag(4, 3))` so _I think_ you could then use `matrix(MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu = c(mu), Sigma = sig1), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence to subset `mu` at every column and `sig1` every 3 columns and pass it to `mvrnorm` function.

```
t(sapply(seq_len(ncol(mu)), function(x) {
   ind <- (x - 1) * 3 
   MASS::mvrnorm(1,mu[,x],sig1[, (ind + 1):(ind + 3)])
}))

#       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
#[1,] 1.0665 3.5964 4.4052
#[2,] 4.9421 9.7464 9.6109
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a `for` loop

```
out <- vector('list', ncol(mu))
sig2 <- list(sig1[, 1:3], sig1[, 4:6])
for(i in seq_len(ncol(mu))) out[[i]] <- MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu[, i], sig2[[i]])
```

---

Or with `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x, y) MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = c(x), Sigma = y), 
         asplit(mu, 2), list(sig1[, 1:3], sig1[, 4:6]))
```

Or `split` the sequence of columns of 'sig1' with `rep`

```
mapply(function(x, y) MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = c(x), 
        Sigma = sig1[, y]), 
          asplit(mu, 2),  split(seq_len(ncol(sig1)), rep(1:2, each = 3)))
```

Comment: nice new function `asplit`

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about the means, a simpler solution would be to simply generate data from standard multivariate data, i.e., MVN(0, Sigma) - and then add to it the different means. This could be faster if you have high data.

E.g. `mus + rmvnorm(n, sigma=Sig)`